# Conversion from character to date/time returns NA

Tags: r, posixct

I often use `as.POSIXct` to convert characters to `POSIXct`, but I get `NA` sometimes and I don't know why. For example:

```
DATE <- "Fri Apr 10 11:57:47 2015"
DATE_in_posix <- as.POSIXct(DATE, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

I tried this too:

```
DATE_in_posix <- as.POSIXct(DATE, format="%a %h %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

But result for both is always:

```
> DATE_in_posix
[1] NA
```

Maybe the input for `as.POSIXct` is too long? And when it's too long what could be the solution?

Comment: both work for me (giving `"2015-04-10 11:57:47 CEST"`)

Comment: Me too `"2015-04-10 11:57:47 CDT"`. Are you sure `DATE` is an object in your code?

Comment: From `?as.POSIXct`: "If `format` is specified, remember that some of the format specifications are locale-specific, and you may need to set the LC_TIME category appropriately via `Sys.setlocale`. This most often affects the use of `%b`, `%B` (month names)". You have weekday name in addition. Also note the "in the current locale" in the description of `%a` and `%b` in `?strptime`.

Comment: I dont really get it how can it NOT be an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because "Fri" and "Apr" are not the correct abbreviations in your locale.

Use `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)` to set your R session's locale to one that will correctly interpret English abbreviations.  See the *Examples* section of `?Sys.setlocale` for how to specify `locale` in the above function call.

For example, on my Ubuntu machine it would be:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
> as.POSIXct("Fri Apr 10 11:57:47 2015", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] "2015-04-10 11:57:47 CDT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Henrik!!!

I changed the LC_TIME category like this, now it works

```
Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")
[1] "German_Germany.1252"

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
[1] "English_United States.1252"

DATE_in_posix<-as.POSIXct(DATE,format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
> DATE_in_posix
[1] "2015-04-10 11:57:47 CEST"
```

and strptime now works too of course

```
DATE_in_posix<-strptime(DATE,format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
> DATE_in_posix
[1] "2015-04-10 11:57:47 CEST"
```

Thank you so much guys and have a nice weekend!